# Jersey / Rest default character encoding

Tags: android, rest, servlets, jersey

Jersey seems to fail when returning JSON...
This:

```
@GET
@Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=UTF-8")
public List<MyObject> getMyObjects() {
    return ....;
}
```

is needed to return JSON utf-8 encoded. If I use only

```
@Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

fails and for example German umlaute (üöä), will be returned in a wrong way.

**Two questions:**
1 - For JSON utf-8 ist standard - why not with Jersey?
2 - Can I set utf-8 for the whole REST-Servlet if a JSON Request comes in?

I am using Jersey 1.5 and CRest 1.0.1 on Android...

Comment: How are they returned? Can you show some sample output?

Comment: It returns LÃ¶we instead of Löwe (Lion in english) but as said if I use @Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=UTF-8") it works...

Comment: I am really the only one who has this problem?

Comment: Well you've solved your own issue then? Just add the charset to the end. It seems to be the client thats displaying the data rather than Jersey.

Comment: Yes, this was the solution for me but it looks a bit odd to me. Is this really the only way to handle this problem?

Comment: I think that it's the client not the server thats having the problem. The client probably doesn't not default to utf-8, and it's only when jersey explicitly states that it's giving back utf-8 content that the client changes it's behaviour. I could be wrong, but I think that's what is going wrong.

Comment: @WhiteMike: I am facing the same issue while receiving the input.  I tried `@Consumes( "*/* ; charset=UTF-8")` but still getting incorrect result.  When I pass **Herman Höhn** from cREST, I am getting it as  **Herman H÷hn**.  Please help receiving the issue.

Answer (score 21):

SRGs suggestion works like a charm. However, since Jersey 2.0 the interfaces are slightly different, so we had to adapt the filter a little bit:

```
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

public class CharsetResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request, ContainerResponseContext response) {
        MediaType type = response.getMediaType();
        if (type != null) {
            String contentType = type.toString();
            if (!contentType.contains("charset")) {
                contentType = contentType + ";charset=utf-8";
                response.getHeaders().putSingle("Content-Type", contentType);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the update! I just started out with using Jersey and stumbled upon this problem, your solution worked flawlessly! Note to Grizzly users: To register this filter, you simply need to call `rc.register(com.example.CharsetResponseFilter.class);` in your startup method (I'm using the generated boilerplate code from the tutorial).

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem : i don't like adding the charset in the "@Produces" tag everywhere.

I found the solution right here : http://stephen.genoprime.com/2011/05/29/jersey-charset-in-content-type.html

Basically, you just have to add a response filter that will add the charset (for example if the content type currently returned is either text, xml or json)

```
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilter;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

public class CharsetResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    public ContainerResponse filter(ContainerRequest request, ContainerResponse response) {

        MediaType contentType = response.getMediaType();
        response.getHttpHeaders().putSingle("Content-Type", contentType.toString() + ";charset=UTF-8");

        return response;
    }
}
```

And to register the filter :

```
ServletAdapter jerseyAdapter = new ServletAdapter();
jerseyAdapter.addInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters", "com.my.package.MyResponseFilter");
```

Works too with Guice, of course, for example in your class extending ServletModule :

```
final Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
parameters.put("com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters", com.package.JerseyCharsetResponseFilter.class.getName());
serve("/*").with(GuiceContainer.class, parameters);
```

Comment: The full, more detailed source of how they implement this [can be found here](https://github.com/tinkerpop/rexster/blob/master/rexster-server/src/main/java/com/tinkerpop/rexster/filter/HeaderResponseFilter.java), and allows for the case where a method has already set the  "Content-Type", thus allowing for overrides where needed.

Answer (score 3):

SRGs and martins solution worked well for me.

However, I had to apply the following changes to the filter:

If the client does a request with an Accept header, Jersey adds a quality factor to the content type. This looks as follows:

**No problem: request without Accept header:**

`curl -i http://www.example.com/my-rest-endpoint`

`response.getMediaType().toString()` is `application/json`. We can simply append `;charset=utf-8`.

**Problem: request with Accept header:**

`curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" http://www.example.com/my-rest-endpoint`

`response.getMediaType().toString()` is `{application/json, q=1000}`. We cannot simply append `;charset=utf-8`, since this would lead to the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error parsing media type '{application/json, q=1000};charset=utf-8'
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MediaTypeProvider.fromString(MediaTypeProvider.java:92) ~[na:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MediaTypeProvider.fromString(MediaTypeProvider.java:60) ~[na:na]
    at javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.valueOf(MediaType.java:179) ~[na:na]
    ...
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Next event is not a Token
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.HttpHeaderReader.nextToken(HttpHeaderReader.java:129) ~[na:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MediaTypeProvider.valueOf(MediaTypeProvider.java:110) ~[na:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MediaTypeProvider.fromString(MediaTypeProvider.java:90) ~[na:na]
    ... 193 common frames omitted
```

---

**I'd suggest the following code to solve this problem:**

```
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

public class CharsetResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request, ContainerResponseContext response) {
        MediaType type = response.getMediaType();
        if (type != null) {
            if (!type.getParameters().containsKey(MediaType.CHARSET_PARAMETER)) {
                MediaType typeWithCharset = type.withCharset("utf-8");
                response.getHeaders().putSingle("Content-Type", typeWithCharset);
            }
        }
    }
}
```