# Jax RS path param not working for accented characters

Tags: java, apache, rest, jax-rs, cxf

Hi I have a jar rs method as below

```
@GET
    @Path("/versioning/{subjectid}")
    @Produces("application/json")
```

where subjectid is the path param

When i invoke the service using the below request

```
/V6.0/xyz/versioning/001033918IN73804CáritaSTG
```

It gets changed to this automatically by apache CXF

```
/V6.0/xyz/versioning/001033918IN73804C%C3%A1ritaSTG
```

I assume CXF is by default encoding the path param

However i get the below error

```
2016-02-22 16:29:49,177 WARNING 

[org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor] (http-127.0.0.1-8092-1) No root resource matching request path
```

Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: maybe this answer will help: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9359728/jersey-web-service-json-utf-8-encoding#answer-9359962)

Answer (score 0):

This change is not made by CXF but by the HTTP client. It encodes the `á` to `%C3%A1`.

CXF is warning about

```
No root resource matching request path
```

This is not a problem of encoding but of the proper use of `@Path` annotations. Check that there really is a method that matches the URL you request.

Comment: If i have normal path param ,(One without accented char) it seems to work fine . Please help

Comment: Can someone please help