# Rest jersey json encoding

Tags: java, json, rest, character-encoding, jersey

I have json responce

```
"storeId": 1,
   "name": "РўРµСЃС‚РѕРІС‹Р№ РјР°РіР°Р·РёРЅ",
   "address": "1Р№ РІРѕР»РѕРєРѕР»Р°РјСЃРєРёР№ РїСЂРѕРµР·Рґ Рґ.10",
   "productIdList":    [
            {
         "productId": 1,
         "productName": "Zewa Deluxe Camomile Comfort",
         "price": 21.3,
      },
            {
         "productId": 2,
         "productName": "РђР»РµРЅРєР°. РњРѕР»РѕС‡РЅС‹Р№ С€РѕРєРѕР»Р°Рґ(РљСЂРІСЃРЅС‹Р№ РћРєС‚СЏР±СЂСЊ)",
         "price": 55,
      },
            {
         "productId": 3,
         "productName": "Safeguard. РџРµРЅРєР° РґР»СЏ РґРµС‚РµР№.",
         "price": 97.5,
      }
   ]
}
```

My headers is

```
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
#status#    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server  Jetty(6.1.25)
Content-Type    application/json; charset=utf-8
```

Charset I declare in my REST annotation:

```
@Produces("application/json;charset=utf-8")
```

How can I fix the problem with this character encoding?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jersey web service json utf-8 encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9359728/jersey-web-service-json-utf-8-encoding)

Comment: Does not work. Have tried all cases from this topic

Comment: What is 'the problem'?

Comment: Do you see JSON responce I have from my rest service? Responce inside my question with understandable characters besides english characters rendered fine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in compile encoding, by default Gradle set platform encoding(in my case Windows)

Setting `compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'` to my build.gradle fix the problem