# Character escaping in Jersey

Tags: java, encoding, jersey, jax-rs, cyrillic

I've got a REST service:

```
@Path(value = "post")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String post(String post) {
    System.out.println(post);
    return post;
}
```

and here's an output: `\u0413\u043e\u0440\u0448`

and that's what expected: `Горш`

I don't know why does it happening, maybe it's because of character escaping. How to fix it and get correct String

Comment: What happens if you add `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")` ?

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9359728/jersey-web-service-json-utf-8-encoding or one of the mentioned answers there will help

Comment: The output remains the same. I think the reason is that I get exactly these symbols (don't know how it's called), not russian letters,  and I need to parse it somehow to characters