# What's the best way to set charset used by jetty and jersey?

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, jersey, jetty

After some googling, I found that:

1. method to set charset for jersey:

   `@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML+"; charset=utf-8")`

   That means I have to add `"; charset=utf-8"` to every restful method. Is there a better way?
2. method to set charset for jetty:
   modify encoding.properties in jar which in default is:

   ```
   text/html   = ISO-8859-1 
   text/plain  = ISO-8859-1 
   text/xml    = UTF-8 
   text/json   = UTF-8
   ```

   But, I don't think It's a good way to modify jars.

Actually, I want to use UTF-8 only to avoid annoying garbled. What is the best way to archive this?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to add the charset in the "@Produces" tag everywhere, you can add it in response filter for all the responses.

```
response.getHttpHeaders().putSingle("Content-Type", contentType.toString() + ";charset=UTF-8");
```

Check this link [Jersey / Rest default character encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514087/jersey-rest-default-character-encoding)