# UTF-8 Encoding using Dropwizard, Hibernate, and MySQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate, dropwizard

I have a MySQL database with a Dropwizard Java application sitting on top of it. I have set up my YAML configuration file according to the [Dropwizard Hibernate](http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.0/docs/manual/hibernate.html) documentation, but for some reason my responses are not being returned UTF-8 encoded.

Answer (score 2):

In the YAML configuration you must be sure to include a `characterEncoding` and `useUnicode` property in addition to the `charSet` property. An example configuration could look like this (note the `properties` section):

```yaml
database:
  driverClass: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  user: ...
  password: ...
  url: jdbc:mysql://...
  properties:
    charSet: UTF-8
    characterEncoding: UTF-8
    useUnicode: true
    hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
  maxWaitForConnection: 1s
  validationQuery: "/* DropWizard Health Check */ SELECT 1"
  minSize: 5
  maxSize: 25
  checkConnectionWhileIdle: false
  checkConnectionOnBorrow: true
```

Updating the YAML configuration in addition to [adding a charset parameter to  the Content-Type header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514087/jersey-rest-default-character-encoding/20569571#20569571) should address the issue.